# Install proprietary graphics driver for GeForce GTX 620 graphics card in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, drivers, software-installation, nvidia-geforce

I have a GeForce GTX 620, and I can't install the proprietary graphics driver in Ubuntu 18.04. I tried downloading and installing the drivers from the NVIDIA website and through the terminal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to switch back to the Nvidia proprietary driver after switching to the open source driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274939/unable-to-switch-back-to-the-nvidia-proprietary-driver-after-switching-to-the-op)

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all the nvidia packages.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt-get remove '^nvidia'
   sudo apt autoremove
   ```
2. If you have added an Nvidia PPA to `/etc/apt/sources.list` remove that PPA by prefacing its line in sources.list with a `#` to comment it out. Run `sudo apt update` to refresh the list of available software.
3. Reboot with `sudo reboot`
4. Run the following command to install the correct proprietary Nvidia driver.

   ```
   sudo ubuntu-drivers install && sudo reboot
   ```

   The `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` command installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies.

Comment: It would (I think) be fair to point out to new users that they can't just use synaptic as their new prescribed uninstallation tool and that it will more than likely end in them destroying their OS as you really have to know what you're doing and understand 100% of it's messages.

Comment: @tatsu Take a look at [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNn2G.png) and you will see in a way how easy it is to achieve the required result in Synaptic. It requires just one mouse click, and you don't need a postgraduate degree to press the button on the mouse.

Comment: In this case I opened my Synaptic Package Manager before I posted anything and performed a dry run walkthrough of the steps without actually uninstalling anything. The procedure in my answer does not remove any other essential packages. You're probably correct that Synaptic can be a sledge hammer in certain situations, but this time it's a screwdriver. I understand your general concerns about using Synaptic, but this time they are unfounded.